# php include_once not working

Tags: php, include

What would be the reasons of a non working include_once?

Here's my folder hierarchy:

```
/Php/Controls/GridView/GridView.php
/Php/Controls/Form/Form.php
```

In "Form.php":

```
include_once '../GridView/GridView.php';
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: include_once(../GridView/GridView.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...Form.php on line 4

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '../GridView/GridView.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in ...Form.php on line 4
```

Please tell me if you want more information.

Comment: Add a `echo getcwd();` before the include. The current path doesn't have to be the location of the file, that's a typical source for this kind of errors.

Comment: The include path is only used, if its a "real" relative path (does not start with `/` or `.`) , but with `.` or `..` it always creates the pathes from the current workdir (see @svens comment)

Comment: possible duplicate of [php include\_once failing despite existence of file and 777 permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808002/php-include-once-failing-despite-existence-of-file-and-777-permissions)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In `Form.php` use

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../GridView/GridView.php';
```

This creates an absolute path, but relative to the file, where its called from.

Answer (score 2):

It can't find the file.

You should use a full path, like `/Php/Controls/GridView/GridView.php` instead of a relative one.

Comment: A problem with an absolute path is that when one decides to move/copy the website, many things will get broken...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
include_once './php/Controls/GridView/GridView.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope I'm not too late on this one but I thought this might be what you're looking for:

```
include_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/../GridView/GridView.php");
```

Using `realpath()` allows you to include files even from outside your server document root directory.