# (PHP): Warning: include_once, failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Im learning how to write a **Sign Up page** using Php and Mysql (XAMPP).

Now, I downloaded the source code in this website:

> http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-a-signup-form-with-email-confirmation/

and tried to make sure it works. But when openning:

```
 http://localhost/source/index.php
```

I got the following warnings:

```
Warning: include_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\source\inc\php\config.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\source\index.php on line 3

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'inc/php/config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\source\index.php on line 3

Warning: include_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\source\inc\php\functions.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\source\index.php on line 4

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'inc/php/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\source\index.php on line 4
```

Here are the lines where I got the warnings:

```
<?php

include_once 'inc/php/config.php';
include_once 'inc/php/functions.php';
.
.
```

Any Help?

Comment: It is what it sais: files cannot be read because server has no permission to do that. Change permissions for the whole directory - you can just grant all permissions, because it is your local server.

Comment: @DmitryScriptin, thanks for answering. But how to do that?

Comment: Well, right click on the folder, select 'Properties' in menu, then 'Security' tab (or whatever it is in your OS) - just google for it a little.

Comment: @DmitryScriptin. Ok, I changed prmissions for th whole directory (including the indix.php file). Still have the same warnings!

Comment: For files too or just a dir? Try to set permission for each of these two files individually and see what happens.

Comment: @DmitryScriptin, This is what I did. I changed prmissions for each file, And for the whole directory.

Comment: What permission have you set?

Comment: I set all of them to "Full control". Besides, What is the second warning?:- Failed opening 'inc/php/config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Comment: For which user or group you set these permissions? It's hard to say what's happening not seeing the whole picture. Second warning is just a consequence of the first.

Comment: I set it for all users and groups (including Administrators) and opened XAMPP as administrator.

Comment: Than my next idea is: what is the `open_basedir` value? `'echo ini_get("open_basedir");` will show it.

Comment: It is OK when it is unset (I have the same setting), so it is not the case. I ran out of ideas now, sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php include\_once not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588639/php-include-once-not-working)

Answer (score 6):

Replace this:

```
include_once 'inc/php/config.php';
include_once 'inc/php/functions.php';
```

with

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/php/config.php';
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/php/functions.php';
```

Comment: This solved it for me.  But don't forget that added first slash in front of 'inc', like I initially did.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the time using full paths like that is disabled in PHP for security reasons, try changing the paths in your include statements to being relative.

Comment: They ARE relative: `'inc/php/config.php'` - absolute whould be `'C:\xampp\htdocs\source\inc\php\config.php'`

Comment: But its not a full path. Its relative to where index.php exists.

Comment: In that case it would appear to be a permissions issue as suggested by @DmitryScriptin

Comment: @TomWalters, how can I change permission to the directory?

Comment: Errors show full path anyway, and do show that permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the folder permission to '754'. Only the folder permission.