# apache2 not loading php codes

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

This index.php file worked fine until recently.
my server is running ubuntu 15.04

i have tried complete reinstalling php5 and apache2 package.

My index.php: http://gyazo.com/26fe168e7bf0695233f61d7d1eb29b47

instead of running the include_once code
it totally ignores it...

what view source from website shows:
http://gyazo.com/09606d26de4fd9002eb3265def95f52c

help?? :(

update: everything works fine in dreamweaver like it supposed to. I think its the serverside problem. I have not altered anything that could cause this screw up >.>

error log

pastebin.com/uZCKUxYh

HTML works fine by its self. php echo works. but my php_includes is causing all the problems

when i add a / into file location (php include_once("/filename.php")) it decides to: gyazo.com/9b530bc9383ab9be534b41e639920f0f  but doesnt show or run the php codes.

Comment: how about file permissions ?

Comment: Can you open a command prompt and type: "php index.php" ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that if you make a simple "Hello World" PHP page the output is empty, right?

```
<?php
echo "Hello world!";
?>
```

Does any error message appears? Has the server actually ever printed anything like a *phpinfo()*, for example?

You could try to restart apache with the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: that works, but as soon as theres html in the .php file. it stops working

Comment: Try to make an easier page that just prints "Hello world" and try to include that and see if it works. Could it be a problem with your code?

Comment: i have echo'd out a word succesfully but the html stops it from working as soon as there's some.

Comment: What does that mean? Can you be a bit more detailed about your problem, maybe post some code?

Comment: i have added more lines to the post. I added the error log, to me it doesnt really say much besides my badly coded line.  i have tried running my website off xampp locally. only thing its throwing is error logs(my sql password login is wrong.[i did not change the password]) but its still not showing my web content.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on and what you're doing but I can see errors in the debug file like _'[Tue Jun 02 21:05:27.617762 2015] [:error] [pid 32207] [client 90.212.48.57:36886] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: user_query in /var/www/html/php_includes/check_login_status.php on line 42'_. Maybe you could try to set _'display_errors = On'_ in your _'php.ini'_ file so that the server prints the error messages, check if it outputs anything.

Comment: i have found out that my website works fine with xamp apache on local computer. but doesnt work when its uploaded to my server. the php includes just wont run

Answer (score 0):

I didnt close a {} so it caused the rest of the codes to not work./...

Answer (score -2):

When you view the sources from your browser you will only see HTML, it is because the server will only return a HTML code.
Is the extension ".php" otherwise it will be treated as a normal HTML page and everything else will be ignored.
If it is a php page, could you post the content of the included files? what do you expect to see?

Edit: after reading the error logs.
From the error logs you posted, you get a lot of file not found errors like :"include_once(): Failed opening '/php_includes/check_login_status.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 13" which is a problem of path.
You may try the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588639/php-include-once-not-working) it tells how to include files the correct way.

Comment: When i call a php file with php_include. it decides to ignore everything from that line downwards.

Comment: Could you post the code of Template_pageTop.php or at least include only one file (with echo "Hello World"; on it) to be sure it is not from the included files?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/9fb0d56aefefed99c053f1366ee4aae2

keep in mind style sheet is called upon index.php and content are all loaded into pageMiddle via .load

Comment: i have found out that my website works fine with xamp apache on local computer. but doesnt work when its uploaded to my server. the php includes just wont run